# looping the str_c( ) function to concatenate columns in order 1 - 100

Tags: r, loops, concatenation

I have a data frame (titled fy14bx) in R.

I need to concatenate 100 columns titled 'onset1' , 'onset2', 'onset3' ... 'onset100' with corresponding columns titled 'x08ddx1' ... 'x08ddx100', generating new columns 'c1' - 'c100'

I'm using stingr, specifically:

```
fy14bx$c1 <- str_c(fy14bx$onset1, "-", fy14bx$x08ddx1)
```

Obviously I don't want to do this manually (I need to do it in 8 other data frames (fy15... etc) where the column names are slightly different also).

Could anyone help me out please?

Thanks

this was no use

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  col_name <- paste0("c", i)
  fy14bx[, col_name] <- str_c(fy14bx[, paste0("onset", i)], "-", fy14bx[, paste0("x08ddx", i)])
}
```

Comment: What would the first resulting correctly named column be?

Comment: Could you clarify what's the issue? Your code looks fine and should give you the desired result when `fy14bx` is a `data.frame`. However, it will not work when `fy14bx` is a `tibble`. In the latter case try with e.g. `fy14bx_tbl[[paste0("onset", i)]]` (which will give a vector) instead of `fy14bx[, paste0("onset", i)]` (which will give a 1-column tibble). For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Comment: You could e.g. use `fy14bx <- data.frame(onset1 = 1:2, onset2 = 3:4, x08ddx1 = 5:6, x08ddx2 = 7:8)` as example data or `fy14bx <- tibble(onset1 = 1:2, onset2 = 3:4, x08ddx1 = 5:6, x08ddx2 = 7:8)` depending on the `class()` of `fy14bx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as expected with a minor tweak:

```r
library(tidyverse)

fy14bx <- data.frame(onset1 = c(1,2,3,4),
                     onset2 = c(5,6,7,8),
                     onset3 = c(9,10,11,12),
                     x08ddx1 = c(101, 102, 103, 104),
                     x08ddx2 = c(105, 106, 107, 108),
                     x08ddx3 = c(109, 110, 111, 112))

fy14bx$c1 <- str_c(fy14bx$onset1, "-", fy14bx$x08ddx1)
fy14bx
#>   onset1 onset2 onset3 x08ddx1 x08ddx2 x08ddx3    c1
#> 1      1      5      9     101     105     109 1-101
#> 2      2      6     10     102     106     110 2-102
#> 3      3      7     11     103     107     111 3-103
#> 4      4      8     12     104     108     112 4-104

for (i in 1:3) {
  fy14bx[[paste0("c", i)]] <- str_c(fy14bx[, paste0("onset", i)], "-", fy14bx[, paste0("x08ddx", i)])
}

fy14bx
#>   onset1 onset2 onset3 x08ddx1 x08ddx2 x08ddx3    c1    c2     c3
#> 1      1      5      9     101     105     109 1-101 5-105  9-109
#> 2      2      6     10     102     106     110 2-102 6-106 10-110
#> 3      3      7     11     103     107     111 3-103 7-107 11-111
#> 4      4      8     12     104     108     112 4-104 8-108 12-112
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: yes! let me try it (I'm working in a secure data environment so I can't cut and paste). thanks!

Comment: yes - thank you that' saved me a lot of keystrokes!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for loops, just use `map2` after getting from the data the columns to be processed.
The data set is from [jared_mamrot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77177429/8245406).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(tidyverse)
)

fy14bx <- data.frame(onset1 = c(1,2,3,4),
                     onset2 = c(5,6,7,8),
                     onset3 = c(9,10,11,12),
                     x08ddx1 = c(101, 102, 103, 104),
                     x08ddx2 = c(105, 106, 107, 108),
                     x08ddx3 = c(109, 110, 111, 112))

onset_cols <- grep("onset", names(fy14bx))
x08_cols <- grep("x08", names(fy14bx))
new_cols <- str_c("c", seq_along(onset_cols))

fy14bx[new_cols] <- map2(
  onset_cols, x08_cols, 
  \(x, y) str_c(fy14bx[[x]], "-", fy14bx[[y]])
)

fy14bx
#>   onset1 onset2 onset3 x08ddx1 x08ddx2 x08ddx3    c1    c2     c3
#> 1      1      5      9     101     105     109 1-101 5-105  9-109
#> 2      2      6     10     102     106     110 2-102 6-106 10-110
#> 3      3      7     11     103     107     111 3-103 7-107 11-111
#> 4      4      8     12     104     108     112 4-104 8-108 12-112
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks Rui! will try Jared's in the first instance and let you know

Comment: Jared's code worked. Thank you for taking the time to provide another avenue - i might use it in the future!

Comment: This is how I would approach this task in my own work; I used loops to make it easier to understand but this is, in my opinion, a better way of handling the problem. The only caveat is that you need to make sure that onset_cols pair up with x08_cols exactly (i.e. you don't have an odd number of columns or a mis-named column). Thanks @Rui Barradas (+1)

Comment: @jared_mamrot I thought of the pairing problem and considered searching for the numbers instead but then I assumed that the `onset` and `x08` columns paired, since they were to be pasted together.